# how to search in html table with any columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

i want to filter or search in this table by using any columns such Title or start date  or visible and so on 
now my code search by first col "Title"only  i can't make it search in all cols 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html that is exactly what i want

```
<div>
    <label>
        Search:<input type="text" id="Search" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search for performance">
    </label>
</div>
<table id="PerformanceTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

    <tr>
        <th>
            Title
        </th>
        <th>
            Start Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Booking
        </th>
        <th>
            Visible
        </th>
        <th>
            Featured
        </th>
        <th>
            Event
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Views)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        // Declare variables
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("Search");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("PerformanceTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the        search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

    }</script>
```

Comment: You have to iterate trough `tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")` collection

Comment: i have 2 errors now 1) can't read uppercase because of date 2) can't read indexof() @hindmost

Comment: Show your changes

Comment: only delete [0] now
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td"); @hindmost

Comment: it make error in function uppercase and index of

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html can you look at this that is exactly what i want and but it doesn't work

Comment: corrected code to make more "read able"

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `.getElementsByTagName("td")[]`

the for loop should be like this:

```js
for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i];
  if (td) {
    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      tr[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through all the `td`s available.  But make sure to break when you find the match.  Example code below:

```
// Declare variables
var input, filter, table, tr, td, i ;
input = document.getElementById("Search");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
table = document.getElementById("PerformanceTable");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"),
th = table.getElementsByTagName("th");

// Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the        search query
for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
            for(var j=0; j<th.length; j++){
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];      
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter.toUpperCase()) > -1)                               {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i try this and i'm sure it's solution but i can't reach  it

Comment: Can you tell what is the exact issue you are getting when you try this.

Comment: Can you tell what is the issue you are getting, so i can help you with the exact usecase.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_table @poushy it's exactly what i do

Comment: can you look at this https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html
that is that exactly what i want but i can't do it

Comment: @amalmansour So basically if it matches I am showing the row.  I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: mmmmm is this filter only by title ?

Comment: that was for the example @amalmansour I've updated the answer.  `filter = input.value.toUpperCase();` .. It should work.