# How to search for second column in table in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

The below code search for the first column of any table on webpage, and i want to search the data from second column. what editing do i need to do to get the desired output ?

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701714/how-to-search-in-html-table-with-any-columns

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>
```

Just use index '1' of td array to get second column.

Comment: Are you sure your table has same column numbers in each row?
And you need to post the error when you say "it's not working".

Comment: I checked it in jsfiddle and its working fine. I guess you have included your js file in wrong place in your HTML. Please check your browser console for any error.

Answer (score 0):

td 0 for first column , td 1 for second column

just change this line from :

> td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

to

> td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>

<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr><td>1</td><td>John</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Jonny</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Ram</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Shyam</td></tr>
</table>
```